# How to use Magento Luma theme for a specific block in the product detail page - product info detailed

Tags: magento2, product, luma-theme, product-review

I am using the Magento 2 Claue Theme for my Magento 2.3 store, I would like to know if I can use the Magento Luma theme for a specific block which is "product info detailed" in the product detail page?

[image]

Comment: Hello, the Claue theme is inherited from Luma? If that's so you should be able to delete the Phtml that overwrites  the original one <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Details" name="product.info.details" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/details.phtml" after="product.info.media">

Comment: @AlanZavagli I was able to change the design by removing the overwrites but the CSS still comes from the Claue Theme, can I have the CSS of luma as well?

Comment: i suggest you to call the Luma css inside catalog_product_view.xml head, this way you'll have the Luma css only inside the product page,

Comment: But, i would suggest to take only the few part of the CSS in Luma and place them inside a custom.css, or going inside Magento 2 design configuration and check on your theme the Parent as Luma